# iPhone OK, but not iPad .. Why?

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios-universal-app

My app works fine on iphone and ipod touch, but shows a blank screen when I launch it on ipad.

When I first created the project I chose the option for builing an iphone/ipad application.
But I never really tested on ipad up to now.

Any idea why it is not working on ipad?

Comment: What are you doing differently on the iPad side? Eg. did you forget something in your AppDelegate/MainViewController/MainWindow.xib?

Comment: Check the iOS version number on iPad..are they both(iPhone/iPad) running over same iOS version? Might be **Deployment target** problem...

Answer (score 0):

After checking and trying a few thing with no success, I finally tried one last which worked.
In the MainWindow_iPad.xib I connected the rootViewController to the top View Controller in my app and it make things work.

I still do not quite understand what is going on though, because this rootViewController is connected to nothing, in the case of MainWindow_iPhone.xib and it works perfectly since the beginning.